# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(Boolean)'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, casting, boolean

While (Goster) field type is integer on Genel_KullaniciMenu context. This query is working. But I changed the type of that field to bit on the database and entity class. then query is not working. It gives error like "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(Boolean)'". What may i change on this query? Thanks for your helps.

```
var query = (from K in
(
 (from Genel_Form in _context.Form
  join Genel_MenuNesne in _context.MenuNesne on new { GenelFormID = Genel_Form.GenelFormID } equals new { GenelFormID = (Genel_MenuNesne.GenelFormID) } into Genel_MenuNesne_join
  from Genel_MenuNesne in Genel_MenuNesne_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join Genel_KullaniciMenu in _context.KullaniciMenu on new { GenelMenuNesneID = Genel_MenuNesne.GenelMenuNesneID } equals new { GenelMenuNesneID = (Genel_KullaniciMenu.GenelMenuNesneID) } into Genel_KullaniciMenu_join
  from Genel_KullaniciMenu in Genel_KullaniciMenu_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join Genel_FormTuru in _context.FormTuru on Genel_Form.GenelFormTuruID equals Genel_FormTuru.GenelFormTuruID into Genel_FormTuru_join
  from Genel_FormTuru in Genel_FormTuru_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join Genel_MenuGrup in _context.MenuGrup on new { GenelMenuGrupID = (Genel_MenuNesne.GenelMenuGrupID) } equals new { GenelMenuGrupID = Genel_MenuGrup.GenelMenuGrupID } into Genel_MenuGrup_join
  from Genel_MenuGrup in Genel_MenuGrup_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join Genel_KullaniciRol in _context.KullaniciRol on new { GenelKullaniciID = (Genel_KullaniciMenu.GenelKullaniciID) } equals new { GenelKullaniciID = Genel_KullaniciRol.GenelKullaniciID } into Genel_KullaniciRol_join
  from Genel_KullaniciRol in Genel_KullaniciRol_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where
    !Genel_FormTuru.FormTuruAdi.Contains("Mobile Ekranlar") &&

          (from Genel_RolGrup in _context.RolGrup
           where

                   (from Genel_KullaniciRol0 in _context.KullaniciRol
                    where
                      Genel_KullaniciRol0.GenelKullaniciID == genelKullaniciID
                    select new
                    {
                        Genel_KullaniciRol0.GenelRolID
                    }).Contains(new { GenelRolID = Genel_RolGrup.GenelRolID })
           select new
           {
               Genel_RolGrup.GenelGrupID
           }).Contains(new { GenelGrupID = Genel_KullaniciMenu.GenelGrupID })
  select new
  {
      MenuGrupAdi = (Genel_MenuGrup.MenuGrupAdi + "-" + Genel_FormTuru.FormTuruAdi.ToUpper()),
      Baslik = (Genel_Form.FormKodu + " " + Genel_MenuNesne.MenuNesneAdi),
      Genel_Form.FormNameSpaceAdi,
      Genel_Form.FormClassAdi,
      Goster = Genel_KullaniciMenu.Goster,       
      GenelGrupID = Genel_KullaniciMenu.GenelGrupID,
      GenelRolID = Genel_KullaniciRol.GenelRolID,
      GenelMenuGrupID = Genel_MenuNesne.GenelMenuGrupID,
      GenelFormTuruID = Genel_Form.GenelFormTuruID,
      GenelMenuNesneID = Genel_MenuNesne.GenelMenuNesneID
  }))
group K by new
{
K.GenelRolID,
K.MenuGrupAdi,
K.Baslik,
K.FormNameSpaceAdi,
K.FormClassAdi,
K.GenelMenuGrupID,
K.GenelFormTuruID,
K.GenelMenuNesneID
} into g
orderby
g.Key.GenelMenuGrupID,
g.Key.GenelFormTuruID,
g.Key.GenelMenuNesneID
select new
{
g.Key.MenuGrupAdi,
g.Key.Baslik,
g.Key.FormNameSpaceAdi,
g.Key.FormClassAdi,
Goster = g.Max(p => p.Goster),

}).ToList()
```

Comment: Have you tried to convert it to int by using: `(int)FieldToConvert`?

Comment: Lord have mercy on he who must debug this code.

Comment: @MaciejLos yes i tried

Comment: @ozziee, where? I do not see...  It should be something like: `(int)p.Goster` or 'Convert.ToInt32(p.Goster)'

Comment: Are you sure the error is in this query? I can't find a Convert.ToInt32() in your query. Is it possible that the error is located elsewhere?

Comment: @MaciejLos as you say i tried like this Goster = g.Max(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.Goster)) then it gives same error. I am freshman at EF.

Comment: @MaciejLos i am using EF Code First

Comment: @Serv  i am using EF Code First

Comment: @Serv I am sure the error is in this query. I debug this code and look for it.

Comment: If you are using EF Code First, Have you migrated your database to reflect the changes in your code? (`update-database` command ) ?

Comment: @Serv I don't use migration for now. So i am not updating database by code.